# Positioning two floating blocks in absolute positioned division

Tags: html, css, css-float, absolute

here is the code

http://jsfiddle.net/77NBM/12/

two grey squeares ("float 1" and "float 2") have to be positioned beside each other in absolute positioned division "submenu_container" related to < li > "menu 3".

Can plz somebody help me to get it? :(

Thx!

Comment: Your menu `li`'s width is 100px and both the floats inside it are alos 100px wide. You can't have them side by side inside a 100px container. Please explain or correct what you're trying to do. Maybe post a screenshot of the end result?

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/846/resultr.jpg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'll always have two elements ("float1 and float2") of 100px each, 
you can set the width of `.submenu_container` to 220px and they will float beside each other. like this http://jsfiddle.net/77NBM/13/
If the width of the elements ("float1 and float2") is dynamic, I suggest you set the width of `.submenu_container` dynamicly width javascript or jQuery. for example:

```
$('#main_menu li').each(function(index) {
    var menuWidth=0;
    $(this).children().children().each(function(index) {
         menuWidth+=$(this).outerWidth();
    }
    $(this).children('.submenu_item').width(menuWidth)
});
```

Comment: Ok, i think the JavaScript solution is the best way for me. Just wanted to figure it out with oure html. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

The width of your submenu is being constrained by the width of your li element, just add some width to your submenu and they should float:left naturally

**CSS**

```
#top{
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
    margin:0px auto;
    background:#ccc;
}

#navigation{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    top:250px;
    left:0px;
    background:#f00
}
#main_menu{
    width:auto;
    height:50px;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#main_menu li{
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    margin-right:10px;
    float:left;
    background:#ff0;
    position:relative;
}

#main_menu li a{
    display:block;
    width:inherit;
    height:inherit;
}

.submenu_container{
    position:absolute;
    background:#00f;
    padding:5px;
    left:-5px;
    width:275px;
}

.submenu_item{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    background:#eee;
    margin:5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/77NBM/17/

By the way, your html markup is full of errors, you need to take a look at that.

**HTML**

```
<div id="top" class="center">
  <div id="navigation">
    <ul id="main_menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 3</a>
        <div class="submenu_container">
          <div class="submenu_item">
            Float 1
          </div>
          <div class="submenu_item">
            Float 2
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx, but i need the "submenu_container" div width to be calculated dependent on it's content width (there may be one, or two or three floating divisions inside). Is it possible? Do you mean line breaks, speaking of html errors?

Comment: then increase the size of your #top div, it is currently set to 500px, if you try to make your submenu open up dependently it will break out of your "top" div.

Comment: Sure, in the original markup the width of the #top div is set wide enough. The problem is to set the position of submenu_container at the right place and to set it's width automatic dependent on it's content. Do you mean it's possible without JavaScript?

Comment: what is the final width of your #top div going to be? Because think about it for a second, imagine that if you have six elements in your drop down menu at the current 500px width of your top div, are you ok with them breaking out of that container? take a look at this example to show you what i mean: http://jsfiddle.net/77NBM/18/

Comment: Yes, it's ok in my case :) (ok, six is a little to much, i'll have 3 max and it's ok)

Comment: If so, then you can be a bit more specific about the size, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/77NBM/20/  (restructured a bit your submenu)

Comment: It's ok... the size is: full width: 960, the navigation block is about 600, placed on a left side. Subemnu can overlap the content on the right. But you still set the submenu container width manually. Is it the only way? Then i have to use JavaScript...

Comment: In this case, yeah, you would have to specify the width of your sub menu manually in order for the elements inside to float left.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #top{
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
    margin:0px auto;
    background:#ccc;
}

#navigation{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    top:250px;
    left:0px;
    background:#f00
}
#main_menu{
    width:auto;
    height:50px;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#main_menu li{
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    margin-right:10px;
    float:left;
    background:#ff0;
}

#main_menu li a{
    display:block;
    width:inherit;
    height:inherit;
}

.submenu_container{
    width:auto;
    position:absolute;
    background:#00f;
    padding:5px;
    left:-5px;
}

.submenu_item{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    background:#eee;
    margin:5px;
}
```